# r.mapcalculator

Tags: qgis, ndvi, qgis-grass-plugin, r.mapcalc

I am using QGIS 2.18.25. I'm struggling to use r.mapcalc to calculate the ndvi for a workbook project. R.mapcalculator is shown on the workbook I'm using and seems simpler to use. Is there a plug-in to load this onto my version or a more user friendly GRASS tool in the version I'm using

Comment: Could you give more details (formula used, workbook extract/links) ?

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at 
[i.vi - Calculates different types of vegetation indices](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/i.vi.html)

Installed via QGIS 2.18.25/ Osgeo4W installer and in the toolbox panel (here in french)

[image: i.vi]

One the indices is NDVI

```
arvi: Atmospherically Resistant Vegetation Index
dvi: Difference Vegetation Index
evi: Enhanced Vegetation Index
evi2: Enhanced Vegetation Index 2
gvi: Green Vegetation Index
gari: Green Atmospherically Resistant Vegetation Index
gemi: Global Environmental Monitoring Index
ipvi: Infrared Percentage Vegetation Index
msavi: Modified Soil Adjusted Vegetation Index
msavi2: second Modified Soil Adjusted Vegetation Index
>> ndvi: Normalized Difference Vegetation Index
pvi: Perpendicular Vegetation Index
savi: Soil Adjusted Vegetation Index
sr: Simple Ratio
vari: Visible Atmospherically Resistant Index
wdvi: Weighted Difference Vegetation Index
```

**NDVI: Normalized Difference Vegetation Index**

```
ndvi( redchan, nirchan )

Satellite specific band numbers ([NIR, Red]):
  MSS Bands        = [ 7,  5]
  TM1-5,7 Bands    = [ 4,  3]
  TM8 Bands        = [ 5,  4]
  Sentinel-2 Bands = [ 8,  4]
  AVHRR Bands      = [ 2,  1]
  SPOT XS Bands    = [ 3,  2]
  AVIRIS Bands     = [51, 29]
```

**Formula :**

```
NDVI = (NIR - Red) / (NIR + Red)
```

**Calculation of NDVI with GRASS**

> The calculation of NDVI from the reflectance values is done as
>   follows:

```
g.region raster=band.3 -p 
i.vi red=band.3 nir=band.4
viname=ndvi output=ndvi r.univar -e ndvi
```

For Sean, to check the Osgeo4W install parameters. It seems i have both grass -&7 install on my machine :

[image: Setup]

Comment: Hi I'm using QGIS 2.18.25. The workbook is Discover QGIS by locate press. Tried looking at i.vi but it's not a GRASS tool in this version of QGIS

Comment: Maybe you need to install QGIS via the osgeo4W advanced installer. I have in in my version (i'll update a picture). You're sure you're looked in the toolbox panel ?

Comment: I did install via osgeo4W advanced installer. Not sure how I can add a screen print to show the GRASS toolbox?

Comment: I updated my answer so you can see what lines I ticked on the osgeo4W install